# Fetch rows in MySQL and return JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following SQL statement. `"SELECT * FROM table"`

Than I do: `echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($query));`

Which gives me a json like this:

```
[
  [
    "32",
    "John",
    "12346",
    "email@gmail.com",
  ]
]
```

This is all fine, but it's missing the field names.

How could I get a JSON like this:

```
[
  [
    "id" : "32",
    "name" : "John",
    "phone" : "12346",
    "email" : "email@gmail.com",
  ]
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: store values with their keys in a new array than use json_encode()

Comment: on a side note: your second example is invalid JSON. the inner quare brackets `[]` should be curly brackets `{}` because with keys, it's not a JSON-array but a JSON-object

Comment: so u not gonna show ur code?

Comment: That output of what you currently get, **just cannot be right please check it**

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, what he currently gets *is* right, except for that last comma. maybe OP was just overzealous while truncating superfluous results?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Are you sure you are looking at what he CLAIM he currently gets, and not what he wants? What he gets should have an **assoc array** and a **numeric array** in that structure if I am not mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you get only numeric indizes. try fetching your data as associative array:

```
echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

see also [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Actually if his dump is correct he gets no indexes at all

Comment: you *can't* have no indizes. but with only numeric ones, json_encode automatically treats it as JSON_array

Comment: Well thats what I would have said, so we assume the OP cannot produce a correct print of his resulting JSON String right?

Answer (score 0):

try `echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC));`

Docu: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

PS: More sophisticated would be to use ORM helper like http://propelorm.org ... saves you a lot of headaches and helps to build maintainable code.